# Materialize CSS Cards equal height and max 3 on row

Tags: html, css, angular, materialize

I have an Angular 4 App with Materialize CSS.
The webpage uses cards and can differ in height so i used flexboxes but then it doesn't maximizes till 3.

When the cards have the same length, there is no problem:
3 cards next to eachother when minimize, it becomes 2 and eventually 1.

But when the cards don't have the same height, I have a row with 3 cards then 1 card and then again 3 cards, this is not what I want.

How can i fix this problem.

HTML-CODE

```
 <div class="row ">
    <ng-template  ngFor let-flow [ngForOf]="data">
    <div *ngIf="flow.id !== currFlow.id" class="col s12 m6 l4">
      <div class="card blue-grey darken-1">
        <div class="card-content white-text">

          <p>
            <strong><b>{{flow.name}}</b></strong>
          </p>

          <form style="overflow: auto; margin-top: 10px;">
            <div class="input-field" style="float:left; width: 50%">
              <input id="type" type="text" value="{{flow.type}}" readonly>
              <label class="active" for="type">Type</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field" style="float: right; width: 50%">
              <input id="update" type="text" value="{{flow.updated_at}}" readonly>
              <label class="active" for="update">Last Update</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field" style="float:left; width: 50%">
              <input id="obs-start" type="text" value="{{flow.observation_start}}" readonly>
              <label class="active" for="obs-start">Start Observation</label>
            </div>
            <div class="input-field" style="float: right; width: 50%">
              <input id="obs-end" type="text" value="{{flow.observation_end}}" readonly>
              <label class="active" for="obs-end">End Observation</label>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
      </ng-template>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
.input-field label {
  color: white
}
input {
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin: 0;
}
```

PICTURE
[image]

**EDIT:**

I now do this:

```
 <div class="row d-flex" *ngFor="let item of specialData">
    <div *ngFor="let flow of item" class="col s12 m6 l4 d-flex">


.d-flex {
  display: inline-flex;
}
```

So for each 3th element a row and display inline-flex.
It works but not for the last row if it hasn't 3 elements.

1 element/card -> the card is floated: right, instead of left...
2 element/cards -> One card is floated: right, the other one is placed in the middle of the 2 first cards above it, instead of two cards next to eachother

Comment: Hey Fangio, do you have the CSS?

Comment: @Most of the css is default by Materialize CSS but I added my CSS file, as you see I also did some styling in my html

Comment: ah right so you don't have any of the flexbox stuff that you're currently using? (apologies, I haven't used materialise to know where it adds it by default)

Comment: i had, but it didn't maximize till 3 so I deleted it

Comment: you can use `flex` and add 4 hidden items that only take width (no height)

Comment: @Dejan. S, what do you mean?

Comment: well instead of having different rows you can just write out like a list in one row (that had flex), at the end add 4 hidden elements that has width and no height (some browsers might require at least 1px height though). It would be much easier to show if you had a fiddle or plunker avaliable.

Comment: Hi, have you solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you are putting all of the card elements in a single row. Try splitting them into multiple row elements, say every third card, based on the index provided by ngFor.

Comment: I have a problem when I do this, I edited my question